# Target Chef Java cookbook recipe version to specific environment

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am fairly new to [chef](/questions/tagged/chef) and I'm looking for the correct way to upgrade [java](/questions/tagged/java) versions on our chef managed servers.

I have 3 chef managed playground environments (*P1*, *P2*, and *P3*)  Normally they are kept the same. except when doing some upgrade like a DB or java upgrade

for each of the environments: The version of the cookbooks are normally identical in *P1*, *P2*, and *P3*. Usually if I update a cookbook, chef normally applies the cookbook change to all 3 environments.  I need to apply the change just to the servers in *P1*.

How do I tell chef to apply the new version of the java cookbook only to the *P1* environment?

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict the cookbook versions that are used per [environment](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#ruby-dsl) using the `cookbook_versions`.

While "unpinned" (not restricted) in *P1*, you add the following to the other two environment definitions:

```rb
cookbook_versions({
  'java' => '< 2.0.0'
})
```

This would restrict these environments to `1.x.y` versions of your `java` cookbook. If everything works out, you release that version constraint by removing it from the other environments.

Optionally, become familiar with the [environment cookbook pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/), which might be overkill for many of us, but IMHO provides a good impression of how an advanced workflow could look like.

Further, the relatively new concept of [Policyfiles](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_policyfile.html) should also provide you means to solve that problem.

Comment: unpinned?   what's that.  new as I said.  Thanks for link will read environment pattern and policyfile

Comment: Not sure if "unpinning" is the officially correct term for that, to be honest. By defining the constraint (i.e. `< 2.0.0`), you _pin_ (restrict, constrain) the version. If you remove it again (or have an environment that does not have such constraint), the cookbook version is not pinned / not constrained / "unpinned" there.

Answer (score 0):

Java version can be specified by using an override attribute in your environment file.

```
"override_attributes": {
    "java": {
      "jdk_version": "8"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually, regarding the first part of the question (_upgrade java versions_), I agree that this could solve the problem. The rest, however, sounds to me more cookbook-focused - it even sounds to me if the OP is using a custom _java_ cookbook.